# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'firebase.apps.length')

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Following is my code

and further if I change from:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

to

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

That`s the second error noted at the end

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/auth';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
// import "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ...................,
  authDomain: ...................,
  projectId: ...................,
  storageBucket: ...................,
  messagingSenderId: ...................,
  appId: ...................
};

let Firebase;

// console.log(firebaseConfig)
if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  Firebase = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
export const firedb = app.firestore 
export default Firebase;
```

For The First Import:

> error :
> ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'firebase.apps.length')
> ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

And For The second:

> Unable to resolve "firebase" from "config\firebase.js"
> Unable to resolve "firebase" from "config\firebase.js"

Comment: replace `firebase.apps.length === 0` with `Firebase?.apps.length === 0` or `!Firebase`

Comment: after the change, the below error occured

ERROR  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: app
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.